# How to add “Download file” link in Drupal 7 files attachment when chosen table formatter

Tags: files

By default Drupal 7 output attached files: **file name** and **size of attachment**
I heed to add an additional column with Download link to every attached file.

In my **template.php** i have added:

```
// Override attachments files in case of use table formatter
function bkisk_file_formatter_table($variables) {
$header = array(t('Attachment'), t('Download'), t('Size')); // added Download column
$rows = array();
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
        $rows[] = array(
            theme('file_link', array('file' => (object) $item)),           
            theme('file_link', array('file' => (object) $item)), // ???
            format_size($item['filesize']),
        );
    }    
    return empty($rows) ? '' : theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}

function bkisk_file_link($variables) {
    $file = $variables['file'];
    $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

    $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
    $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

    // Set options as per anchor format described at
    $options = array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
        ),
    );

    // Use the description as the link text if available.
    if (empty($file->description)) {
        $link_text = $file->filename;
    }
    else {
        $link_text = $file->description;
        $options['attributes']['title'] = 'откроется в новой вкладке';
        $options['attributes']['target'] = '_blank'; // add _blank param
    }
    return '<span class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span>';
}
```

**i have** https://i.stack.imgur.com/W76kW.png

**i need to do like this** https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmKMj.png

ill be very appreciated for your help!

Comment: if form link this way `l('Download', $item['uri']),` it creates path to file domain.com/public%3A//files/23/ustav_gup_sk_bki_sk_no795_ot_16.06.14.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

partially solve task by adding to file_link() function construction

```
function bkisk_file_link($variables) {
    $file = $variables['file'];
    $icon_directory = $variables['icon_directory'];

    $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
    $icon = theme('file_icon', array('file' => $file, 'icon_directory' => $icon_directory));

    // Set options as per anchor format described at
    $options = array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => $file->filemime . '; length=' . $file->filesize,
        ),
    );

    // Use the description as the link text if available.
    if (empty($file->description)) {
        $link_text = $file->filename;
    }
    else {
        $link_text = $file->description;
        $options['attributes']['title'] = 'откроется в новой вкладке';
        $options['attributes']['target'] = '_blank'; // add _blank param

        $options_download['attributes']['title'] = 'Скачать ' . "[" . $link_text . "]";
        $options_download['attributes']['download'] = '';
    }
    return '<span class="file">' . $icon . ' ' . l($link_text, $url, $options) . '</span><br /><br />' .
           '<span class="file-download">' . l('Download', $url, $options_download) . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [File Force Download](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_force) module to add download functionality to your site. It has field formatter, views integration, good api and etc..

If you want to create a download link programmatically then you can generate download link such way:

```
l('Linktext', file_force_create_url($image['filepath']), array('query' => array('download' => '1'))).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have installed and activate File Force Download module, then add link formatter programmaticlly to template.php, but it transfer only argument /?download=1 in to address field

Comment: i am not agree with you. You're giving wrong path I think

Comment: try to see what happens when i add this costruction in foreach cycle bkisk.ru/contacts/constituent-documents, it just add additional query to addressbar in browser. i60.tinypic.com/30vdbbm.png